# XSLT transform: how to preserve the element's attributes during transform?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a function in C# to take XML data and sort it using an XSLT style sheet, and then return the sorted data and put it into an XMLDocument object. The XSLT will process the data without error but it doesn't return all of the data correctly. As you can see below the attributes of CarerContent are missing.

This is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="MatchedSources">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="OverallMatchValue"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input XML data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MatchedSources responseId="1" dataSourceType="Document">
    <MatchedSource>
        <SourceId>1001</SourceId>
        <DifferentPerspectives>
            <Carer>
                <CarerContent id="1" title="text">content</CarerContent>
                <CarerContent id="2" title="text">content</CarerContent>
            </Carer>
        </DifferentPerspectives>
        <OverallMatchValue>45</OverallMatchValue>
    </MatchedSource>
   <MatchedSource>
        <SourceId>1002</SourceId>
        <DifferentPerspectives>
            <Carer>
                <CarerContent id="1" title="text">content</CarerContent>
                <CarerContent id="2" title="text">content</CarerContent>
            </Carer>
        </DifferentPerspectives>
        <OverallMatchValue>78</OverallMatchValue>
    </MatchedSource>
</MatchedSources>
```

And the resulting output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MatchedSources responseId="1" dataSourceType="Document">
    <MatchedSource>
        <SourceId>1002</SourceId>
        <DifferentPerspectives>
            <Carer>
                <CarerContent id="1" title="text">content</CarerContent>
                <CarerContent id="2" title="text">content</CarerContent>
            </Carer>
        </DifferentPerspectives>
        <OverallMatchValue>78</OverallMatchValue>
    </MatchedSource>
   <MatchedSource>
        <SourceId>1001</SourceId>
        <DifferentPerspectives>
            <Carer>
                <CarerContent>content</CarerContent>
                <CarerContent>content</CarerContent>
            </Carer>
        </DifferentPerspectives>
        <OverallMatchValue>45</OverallMatchValue>
    </MatchedSource>
</MatchedSources>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it's a common easy mistake.
The `<xsl:copy>` only copy the element itself, it's equivalent to `<xsl:element name="{name()}">`. You need to explicitely copy attributes nodes.

For example, just switch your default template by :

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you want to have some specific behavior for some attributes use a complete "match design" :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="MatchedSources">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-template/>
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="OverallMatchValue"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about the [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) - and use it instead of your second template.